# Adding a new user to Rally in Java

Tags: java, rally

I am looking for any code available to add new users in Rally written in Java? If it is already there somewhere, i would like to get the same. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I see code around Ruby for the user management, but not in Java. Is java technically feasible for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically feasible to use Java REST toolkit since it is using the same WS API as the Ruby REST toolkit. Here is a sample code that creates a user:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class aRestcreateUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        //Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        String myRallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String myRallyUser = "administrator@company.com"; //must have admin rights
        String myRallyPassword = "adminPassword";

        String wsapiVersion = "1.43";
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
            new URI(myRallyURL),
            myRallyUser,
            myRallyPassword);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        System.out.println(restApi.getWsapiVersion()); 


        try {

            System.out.println("Creating User...");
            JsonObject newUser = new JsonObject();
            newUser.addProperty("UserName", "nick002@test.com");
            newUser.addProperty("EmailAddress", "nmusaelian@rallydev.com");

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("User", newUser);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

            if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Created User %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));

                String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                System.out.println(String.format("\nReading User %s...", ref));
                GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                System.out.println(String.format("Read User. Name = %s, State = %s",
                        obj.get("UserName").getAsString(), obj.get("EmailAddress").getAsString()));

            } else {
                String[] errorList;
                errorList = createResponse.getErrors();
                for (int i=0;i<errorList.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println(errorList[i]);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            //Release all resources
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
}
```